# I'm trying to make a Javascript calculator as part of a freecodecamp task but can't get it to work with IDs and data-operators

Tags: javascript, html

I've added ids and data operators and numbers to the html but the output still shows "NaN on the screen

I've tried to test it in the suite but the following tests don't pass:

1. My calculator should contain 10 clickable elements containing one number each from 0-9, with the following corresponding IDs: id="zero", id="one", id="two", id="three", id="four", id="five", id="six", id="seven", id="eight", and id="nine".
2. My calculator should contain 4 clickable elements each containing one of the 4 primary mathematical operators with the following corresponding IDs: id="add", id="subtract", id="multiply", id="divide".
3. My calculator should contain a clickable element with an id="clear"
4. At any time, pressing the clear button clears the input and output values, and returns the calculator to its initialized state; 0 should be shown in the element with the id of "display"

   5.At any time, pressing the clear button clears the input and output values, and returns the calculator to its initialized state; 0 should be shown in the element with the id of "display"
5. In any order, I should be able to add, subtract, multiply and divide a chain of numbers of any length, and when I hit "=", the correct result should be shown in the element with the id of "display"
6. In any order, I should be able to add, subtract, multiply and divide a chain of numbers of any length, and when I hit "=", the correct result should be shown in the element with the id of "display"
7. I should be able to perform any operation (+, -, *, /) on numbers containing decimal points
8. I should be able to perform any operation (+, -, *, /) on numbers containing decimal points

I'm guessing I have to use a switch statement somewhere? 
Can anyone help me? Thank you.

```js
function getHistory() {
  return document.getElementById('previous-operand').innerText;
}

function printHistory(num) {
  document.getElementById('previous-operand').innerText = num;
}

function getOutput() {
  return document.getElementById('display').innerText;

}

function printOutput(num) {
  if (num == "") {
    document.getElementById('display').innerText = num;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('display').innerText = getFormattedNumber(num);
  }
}

function getFormattedNumber(num) {
  if (num == "minus") {
    return "";
  }
  var n = Number(num);
  var value = n.toLocaleString("en");
  return value;
}

function reverseNumberFormat(num) {
  return Number(num.replace(/,/g, ''));
}
var operator = document.getElementsByClassName("operator");
for (var i = 0; i < operator.length; i++) {
  operator[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (this.id == "clear") {
      printHistory("");
      printOutput("");
    } else if (this.id == "backspace") {
      var output = reverseNumberFormat(getOutput()).toString();
      if (output) { //if output has a value
        output = output.substr(0, output.length - 1);
        printOutput(output);
      }
    } else {
      var output = getOutput();
      var history = getHistory();
      if (output == "" && history != "") {
        if (isNaN(history[history.length - 1])) {
          history = history.substr(0, history.length - 1);
        }
      }
      if (output != "" || history != "") {
        output = output == "" ?
          output : reverseNumberFormat(output);

        history = history + output;
        if (this.id == "=") {
          var result = eval(history);
          printOutput(result);
          printHistory("");
        } else {
          history = history.this.id;
          printHistory(history);
          printOutput("");
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
var number = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
  number[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    //get output commas removed
    var output = reverseNumberFormat(getOutput());
    //  
    if (output != NaN) { //if output is a number
      output = output + this.id;
      printOutput(output);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="calculator-grid" class="calculator-grid">
  <div class="output">
    <div id="previous-operand"></div>
    <div id="display"></div>
  </div>
  <button data-operator="clear" class="operator">AC</button>
  <button data-operator="del" class="operator">DEL</button>
  <button data-operator="divide" id="divide" class="operator">÷</button>
  <button data-number="1" id="one" class="number">1</button>
  <button data-number="2" id="two" class="number">2</button>
  <button data-number="3" id="three" class="number">3</button>
  <button data-operator="multiply" class="operator">*</button>
  <button data-number="4" id="four" class="number">4</button>
  <button data-number="5" id="five " class="number">5</button>
  <button data-number="6" id="six" class="number">6</button>
  <button data-operator="add" id="add" class="operator">+</button>
  <button data-number="7" id="seven" class="number">7</button>
  <button data-number="8" id="eight" class="number">8</button>
  <button data-number="9" id="nine" class="nine">9</button>
  <button data-operator="minus" id="subtract" class="operator">-</button>
  <button data-operator="decimal" id="decimal" class="operator">.</button>
  <button data-number="0" id="zero" class="number">0</button>
  <button data-operator="equals" id="equals" class="span-two operator">=</button>
</div>
```

Comment: As is your question is quite hard to digest, can you edit it to be a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

I've made a Codepen to demonstrate your app with minimal styling, I recommend you do this the next time you're asking for help.

https://codepen.io/bashuatdiff/pen/JjoQZoe

I believe the "NaN" value is returned by this function.

```
function getFormattedNumber(num) {
  if (num == "minus") {
    return "";
  }
  var n = Number(num);
  var value = n.toLocaleString("en");
  return value;
}
```

The problem is that you're passing in a **string** to this function - that is, the `id` value of the Number Button that was clicked, appended to the current Output value. Then you use `Number(num)` to coerce this string to a number.

Any time you try to create a Number from a string with non-digit characters, the result will be NaN. In this case your `id` values are "one", "two", etc, none of which can be coerced to a Number - you'll end up with NaN.

Possible solutions:

1. Don't use word values for your `id` attributes. Instead of "two", use "2". More generally, you're converting back and forth between strings and numbers a lot throughout this code, and it will help to be aware of when you're expecting a string and when you're expecting a number.
2. Convert the `id` attribute to a number before concatenating it to the output. It's important to understand when the Plus symbol (+) is [concatenating](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/concatenating-strings-with-plus-operator) and when it's [adding](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascriptss-addition-operator-demystified/).
3. Add checks for "NaN" throughout your code. You had one: `output != NaN` but this [won't actually work.](https://dmitripavlutin.com/nan-in-javascript/) Even `NaN` isn't equal to `NaN`. Instead, try something like `typeof output == "number"`.

Good luck.